# Populate data from model into handlebar template

Tags: ember.js

I have the following rout that returns a json resoponse from the server.

```
    myApp.VcustomersInvoiceRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    order_id: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  model: function(params) {
    var url = 'ajax_handler/getorderdetails/' + params.order_id;

    return Ember.$.getJSON(url)
  },
   setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

Server response:

```
[{"id":"1929","firstname":"Aaron","lastname":"Loeb","dayphone":"650 - 346 - 8668","email":"aaronloeb@gmail.com","street":null,"city":null,"zipcode":null,"pickuptime":"02:00:00","pickupdate":"02:00:00","location":"4th Street","type":"Web order"}]
```

controller:

```
    myApp.VcustomersInvoiceController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    adding:false,
    isEditing:false,
  actions: {
        editorederdetails: function() {
            this.set('isEditing', true);

        },
        isadding: function() {
            if (this.adding){
                    this.set('adding', false)
                    $("#add").show();
                }else{
                    this.set('adding', true)
                    $("#add").hide();
                };

        },
    },
});
```

what I am trying to achieve is display data from this response into the template. Something like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="vcustomers/invoice">

<h1>Invoice <small># {{id}}</small></h1>
<h1>Customer <small># {{lastname}}</small></h1>
```

Route structure:

```
myApp.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('vcustomers', function () {
    this.route('invoice', { path: '/invoice/:invoice_id' });
});
this.resource('vmenus');
this.resource('creport');
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass one object, instead of an array with one object inside, to your controller. Then you can access its properties easily. Change your `setupController` method to:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  controller.set('model', model.get('firstObject'));
}
```

And then you can access model properties using:

```
<h1>Invoice <small># {{model.id}}</small></h1>
<h1>Customer <small># {{model.lastname}}</small></h1>
```

Which produces:

```
Invoice # 1929

Customer # Loeb
```

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pesoqijidu/2/edit)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, It actually works. One more question before I mark as resolved. Is this a good practice or there is a better approach?

Comment: Yes,  there is a better approach,  but it involves complete redesign of your invoice route and structuring invoices as Ember Data models.  Then you create route with path :invoice_id and access model properties in template same way like in my answer. I encourage you to read about models and routes in Ember guide.

Comment: Yeah I see now that you're using `order_id`. So now I've got 1 suggestion for you: 1. Change your backend to return only one record instead of array when you find record by id. You can also leave everything as it is because it's not so bad approach, but it could be better(if you change your backend).

Comment: It's strange that you declare in Router `/invoice/:invoice_id`, but you use `params.order_id` in your model. It should be `params.invoice_id`. It also seems that you're using custom ajax calls and you don't use Ember Data so you won't benefit of its features.

Comment: change the json response structure? could you send me a sample please?

Comment: You don't use Ember Data, so your only choice is: `{"id":"1929","firstname":"Aaron","lastname":"Loeb","dayphone":"650 - 346 - 8668","email":"aaronloeb@gmail.com","street":null,"city":null,"zipcode":null,"pickuptime":"02:00:00","pickupdate":"02:00:00","location":"4th Street","type":"Web order"}` Remove brackets so you don't need to use `model.get('firstObject')`.